# Changing Y values in a chart

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Here is the updated code:

```
private function myFillFunction(element:ChartItem, index:Number, item:Object,     
fieldName:String):IFill {
    var c:SolidColor = new SolidColor(0x00CC00);
    var ci:ColumnSeriesItem = ColumnSeriesItem(element);

    c.color = 0xFF2020;
    if ( Number(ci.yValue) >= 0 ) {
        c.color = 0x5586E0;
    } 

    if(fieldName == "yValue"){
        item.price= Math.abs( item.price);
    }
    else{
        item.date = item.date;
    }

    return c;
}
```

I get the following error:
ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on index/myFillFunction(). Expected 4, got 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the absolute of a value much easier than what you are attempting by calling the *abs()* method of the Math class:

```
Math.abs(value);
```

however, the error is saying that you are trying to send 3 parameters to your *fixNegatives(element:ChartItem)* function while it can only receive the one *ChartItem* object.

Comment: thx, but what do I put in the "return"? I have item.price = Math.abs( item.price); return item.price; However, this just returns 1 big huge column & no other columns.

Comment: please post all relevant code in your original question so i can see exactly what you're doing

Comment: it would be easier to forgo using your fixNegatives() function and simply assign the price value of the data provider as an absolute value.  something like:  data.price = Math.abs(price);